# Converting visa status from B1/B2 to F1

Tags: b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I currently have a B1/B2 visa and am applying to universities in the US. If I get admitted for fall semester, I can only go about a month before my courses start, i.e. about july. But, I have a family function to attend in June. What are my options here in terms of being able to enter in the US before the 30 day barrier on my B1/B2 visa and preferably convert it to F1 visa there?

I’m an Indian btw

Comment: Keep in mind that if you change status to F-1 with USCIS inside the US, that will not get you a new visa. The very next time you enter the country after changing, you will have to get a new visa from your home country embassy.

Comment: I'm an Indian btw

Answer (score 10):

Trying to do a Change of Status in the US from B2 to F1 is a bad idea. The reason is that you are not allowed to start studying until the Change of Status is approved, and processing times for Change of Status can be 5-6 months or more. So you will miss the start of your classes and your school will have to push back your starting date. (And if Change of Status takes so long that your B2 status is going to expire, you would have to file a separate Extension of Status application to extend your B2 status to bridge the gap.)

It is much easier to leave the US after your function and re-enter on an F1 visa.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As a follow up, am I required to return to India? Or can I go to Canada and then enter into US from there. Any suggestions on this approach?

Comment: @NikhilSingh Yes, you can do it by leaving and re-entering, for example at a road crossing.

Comment: @NikhilSingh To avoid misunderstandings, at the border, never hand over the passport open at the main page. The first time, show the B1/B2 visa; when re-entering from Canada, the F1 visa **and also** the I-20 letter

Comment: You are asking for trouble. You want to go to Canada and enter with what visa? B1/B2 again? Who said you are guaranteed reentry? Go back to India and apply for a students visa. If you follow immigration news you would realize this is absolutely the wrong time to try gaming the system.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, however the parenthetical mark is incorrect. With a timely filed Change of Status application, it is not required to maintain status during its pendency.

Comment: @Brian: It is correct that you are not required to maintain status during a pending Change of Status. However, USCIS will only approve a Change of Status to F1 if you are in status 30 days before the start of the program. If the Change of Status taking too long causes you to miss the start of the program, the school will postpone your start date, and USCIS requires you to be in status 30 days before the *new* start date. This effectively means you must maintain status until very close to the approval of the Change of Status.

Comment: @Brian: See the bullet point in "What if I Have a Gap in Status?" on [this page](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment/changing-a-nonimmigrant-f-or-m-student-status)

Comment: @user102008 I see, I understand what you're saying now. The postponement of the start date is what causes the issue. That makes sense.

Comment: @user 56513 just mentioning an approach someone suggested. Anyways, what happens exactly to my B1/B2 visa if I apply for an F1 visa in say March? I mean, any of this is only possible only if they don't scrap the B1/B2 when I get my F1.